# Pass std::string to OpenCL Kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to pass a string into an OpenCL kernel. Here is my c++ code abbreviated:

```
std::string a = "abcd";
char *aChar = new char[a.size()+1];
aChar[a.size()] = 0;
memcpy(aChar, a.c_str(), a.size());

cl::Buffer serverKeyBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, sizeof(char) * a.size(), aChar);
```

Signature for the kernel is:

```
__kernel void MyKernel(__global float* rollNumber, __global char* a)
```

I keep getting a -51 (CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE). Not really sure why the size would be invalid

Comment: Which API call is returning that error code?

Comment: maybe use `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`. then it is also not necessary to copy the string out of the `std::string`.

Comment: @Dithermaster it was the `kernel.setArg` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `serverKeyBuffer` to `setArg` right ? The correct length for passing buffer arguments (`arg_size` parameter of `clSetKernelArg`) is `sizeof(cl_mem)` (usually == sizeof(void*)) - not the size of buffer's underlying storage. Unfortunately i don't know much about the C++ API and how it handles arguments...

Comment: Yes passing `serverKeyBuffer` to `setArg`. The C++ wrapper `setArg` wraps `clSetKernelArg`. So would it be something like `clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), aChar)`

Answer (score 3):

Got it working. I realized I wasn't passing this in as a buffer. Here is the fixed code:

```
std::string a = "abcd";
char *aChar = new char[a.size()+1];
aChar[a.size()] = 0;
memcpy(aChar, a.c_str(), a.size());

cl::Buffer serverKeyBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, strlen(aChar), NULL);
kernel.setArg(1, serverKeyBuffer);

...

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(serverKeyBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, strlen(aChar), aChar);
```